# django module object is not callable

Tags: python, django

running Django 1.8.4 and trying to get zinnia 0.15.2 working and when I try to run my first migrations I get this traceback...

```
STOP_WORDS = stop_words(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE.split('-')[0])
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Now this is within the zinnia settings file. At the top it imports the django settings with...

```
from django.conf import settings
```

I just can't figure out why it would be failing there, everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the mots_vides module was for some reason filled with empty files.

```
pip install -U mots_vides
```

did not change anything I had to do

```
pip uninstall mots_vides 
pip install mots_vides
```

and then it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

I often use a construct like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

LANGUAGE_CODE = settings.getattr("LANGUAGE_CODE", None)

STOP_WORDS = stop_words(LANGUAGE_CODE.split('-')[0])
```

This way I catch an error if LANGUAGE_CODE is not set

Comment: but I have checked, and the language code is set so I don't think that can be the problem in this case

Comment: Can you post your settings.py and the full stacktrace?

Comment: I can, but I think I have traced it down, the stop_words file has nothing in it, from the mots_vides module. I guess I have to figure out what that is